# How to turn on screen magnifier support on Google Doc under Firefox (Mac)?

Tags: macos, firefox, accessibility, google-docs, magnifier

In Google Doc under Chrome browser (on Mac), I am able to turn on the screen magnifier support under Tools->Accessibility settings.
[image: Chrome case]

However, I am not able to find such feature under Firefox. How can I make it? If impossible, how do I achieve a similar effect?
[image: Firefox case]

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome pref says 'Works with 3rd party screen magnifier software".

The Mac doesn't need 3rd party software, it's built-into the OS.
Web pages will zoom in/out with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>   or  <kbd>-</kbd>   and will return to default with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd> . Alternatively, there's a whole screen magnifier in System prefs > Accessibility > Zoom.

Comment: Actually, the reason that I posted this question is not for magnification. Turning on that magnifier support somehow solves a Googld Doc bug for certain language input methods. I have tried the System prefs option but that does not solve the bug I am facing. I am wondering why Firefox does not have that same option as Chrome does.